# Python Pandas apply a string splitting function to an index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a Pandas DataFrame containing Postcodes and counts. It has been created using `value_count`.

The DataFrame looks like this:

```
          count
Postcode       
AL1 1AJ     151
AL1 1AR      36
AL1 1AS      21
AL1 1AT      12
AL1 1AU      11
...         ...
YO8 9YD      10
YO8 9YE       4
YO90 1UU      2
YO90 1WR      1
YO91 1RT      1
```

I am attempting to split the index column using a string splitting function. My objective is to chop each postcode, returning only the first part.

Here's a function which does (should do?) that.

```
def split_postcode(postcode):
    postcode_parts = postcode.split(' ')
    
    if len(postcode_parts) == 2:
        return postcode_parts[0]
    elif len(postcode_parts) == 1:
        return postcode
    else:
        print(f'unexpected postcode length: {len(postcode_parts)}')
```

I tried to apply it with

```
# value_count_df is the above DataFrame
value_count_df.apply(split_postcode, axis=0)
```

but this failed with the error

```
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values have 2 elements
```

What I am trying to do probably doesn't make much sense, because if I recall correctly, index columns are immutable.

So I'm not sure how to proceed.

It is likely that I created this DataFrame in a way which is less suitable than an alternative.

---

Here's some information about how I created the `value_count_df` object.

- I read Postcode data from an SQL file, and inserted all the values into a list.
- I then did this:

```
postcode_df = pandas.DataFrame(postcode_list)
postcode_df.columns = ['Postcode']
    
value_count = postcode_df.value_counts()
    
value_count_df = pandas.DataFrame(value_count)
value_count_df.columns = ['Postcode', 'Count']
value_count_df = value_count_df.sort_index()

# fails
value_count_df.apply(split_postcode, axis=0)
```

How should I do things differently to achieve a sensible result?

The final objective is to truncate the postcodes down to just the "first" part of the postcode (split by space `' '` character, and return the first string) and then obtain the value counts for each unique string.

I currently have value counts for each unique postcode, I just want to repeat this for the "truncated" postcode.

I could do it by creating a new list of truncated postcodes from the existing list, but this seems inefficient, and it would be good to lean how to do it using the data in the DataFrame directly.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use simple `.str.split`:

```py
first_part = df.index.str.split(" ").str[0]
print(first_part)
```

Prints:

```
Index(['AL1', 'AL1', 'AL1', 'AL1', 'AL1', 'YO8', 'YO8', 'YO90', 'YO90',
       'YO91'],
      dtype='object', name='Postcode')
```

---

If you want uniques:

```
print(first_part.unique())
```

Prints:

```
Index(['AL1', 'YO8', 'YO90', 'YO91'], dtype='object', name='Postcode')
```

---

If you want to set index:

```
df.index = df.index.str.split(" ").str[0]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
          count
Postcode       
AL1         151
AL1          36
AL1          21
AL1          12
AL1          11
YO8          10
YO8           4
YO90          2
YO90          1
YO91          1
```

Comment: AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with Index, not MultiIndex ?

Comment: Any thoughts on why this happens or how to fix it?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant You can use `df.index.get_level_values(0).str.split(" ").str[0]`  (change the `0` in `get_level_values()` to level from where you want the values).